# Pandas Index Match Alternative as in Excel

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, lookup, matching

In the following table I have a list of dates. I am trying to index the second dataframe and extract the corresponding value in the first dataframe. I want to create column D.

I have referenced 
[Pandas Merge returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754398/pandas-merge-returns-nan) 
as well, and both columns are indeed the same type(str)

```
print(data)

A          B
1/1/17     15
1/2/17     16
1/3/17     14
1/4/17     15
1/5/17     16
1/6/17     14
1/7/17     15
1/8/17     16
1/9/17     14

print(lookup)

C         D
1/4/17    15
1/7/17    15
1/8/17    16
```

So basically I have the 'data' pandas dataframe, but I dont know how to create a column D in the 'lookup' dataframe to populate the two 15 and the 16 values. This is a smaller example of a bigger problem, Im trying to utilize a similar reference table to create a column in a much larger dataframe that pulls off the reference table. The dates in column C clearly already exist in the lookup dataframe as they are what im trying to use as a reference.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: just for clarity: do you want find all the 'B' value that match 1/4/15 and 1/7/15?

Comment: Do you want the year (I assume these are dates) to be ignored when matching?

Comment: enneppi - Yes. I would like to create column D, which is filled with the corresponding date values from column B. There are also a number of other columns on each of these dataframes, and I need to preserve all of the columns in 'lookup'. And 

Rahlf23 - no, I need to match the exact dates, I wrote the wrong dates and have now corrected. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, answer below.

Comment: @FrankDrin I understood the matter, see answer below

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need is just a simple merge of two dataframe:

```
lookup.merge(data, left_on='C', right_on='A', how='left')
```

That's all

Comment: Thanks for the help enneppi, but when I do this, my Lookup frame just has a blank column added. Something is breaking with the 'merge', and im not sure what as im pretty sure my 'A' and 'C' columns are the same format. Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
lookup['D'] = [data.B[data.A[data.A==i].index[0]] for i in lookup.C.tolist()]
```

Explanation:

Creates a new column in `lookup` called 'D' that is the value of column 'B' in `data` that corresponds to when the value in column 'A' in `data` is equal to the current element being iterated on in the list of values from column 'C' in `lookup`

Comment: I tried this as well as jpp's answer below. For this answer I received the error 'IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0'. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

This is one straightforward method:

```
lookup['D'] = lookup['C'].map(data.set_index('A')['B'])
```

You can also reach this result via `pd.merge`, but the above is likely more efficient.

**Explanation**

- `data.set_index('A')['B']` creates a `pd.Series` mapping 'A' to 'B'. This works because the indices are unique.
- [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) can take a series as an input.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Unfortunately this produces a column of NaN so the lookup is failing somehow. When I run type on a value for each, they are both <class 'str'> so im not sure why its failing...