# Convert object data type to string issue in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I convert an object dtype structure to a string dtype? The method below is not working and the column remains `object` after converting to a string with `.astype`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})

df.dtypes
#country    object
#dtype: object

df['county'] = df['country'].astype(str)

df.dtypes
#country    object
#dtype: object
```

Comment: `pandas V 1.0` introduced [`StringDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype) - check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dtypes) for more info on dtypes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`object` is the default container capable of holding strings, or any combination of dtypes.

If you are using a version of pandas < `'1.0.0'` this is your only option. If you are using `pd.__version__ >= '1.0.0'` then you can use the [new experimental `pd.StringDtype()` dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#dedicated-string-data-type). Being experimental, **the behavior is subject to change in future versions, so use at your own risk**.

```
df.dtypes
#country    object

# .astype(str) and .astype('str') keep the column as object. 
df['country'] = df['country'].astype(str)
df.dtypes
#country    object

df['country'] = df['country'].astype(pd.StringDtype())
df.dtypes
#country    string
```

Answer (score 9):

I got it to work using `'string'` instead of `str`

```
df['country'] = df['country'].astype('string')
df.dtypes
#country    string
```

Comment: Amazing - but what stopped/would stop `str` working - null values perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting it to a `str`. `non-null object` is how pandas handles `str` in some cases.

Check out this [article](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html) on pandas data types.

Check out the most recent official [docs on dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dtypes).