# Vectorized string methods- Despite adding the datatype as string, the O/P shows datatype as object. I even wrote it as dtype="str"

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd

sss2 = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'Aaba', 'Baca', np.nan, 'CABA', 'dog', 'cat'],dtype="str")
sss2
```

Please advise

Comment: what is your pandas version? there is no `dtype` as `str` though `string` is supported from pandas `1.0` onwards , or `object` otherwise`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581893/convert-object-data-type-to-string-issue-in-python. `str`, and `'str'` are still considered `object` (likely for compatibility). `'string'` is the correct way to convert to the new experimental pd.StringDtype if using pandas > 1.0. If you hate that subtle difference, then use the explicit `dtype=pd.StringDtype()`

Comment: I did use dtype=pd.StringDtype() but despite that the issue persists as well as dtype="string'