# Pandas, object column to string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas df:

```
      first   second    third fourth fifth
0       x       y        12     2      0
1       a       b         1     1      1
2       c       d         2    12      0
```

To check column data types, I use:

```
df.info()
```

It is result:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
first    380 non-null object
second   380 non-null object
third    380 non-null object
fourth   380 non-null object
fifth    380 non-null int32
```

I want to convert first and second column into string:

```
df['first'] = df['first'].astype(str)
df['second'] = df['second'].astype(str)
```

I want to check that:

```
df.info()

first    380 non-null object
second   380 non-null object
third    380 non-null object
fourth   380 non-null object
fifth    380 non-null int32
```

So it does not worked, where did I made a mistake?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581893/convert-object-data-type-to-string-issue-in-python

Answer (score -1):

Pandas API has slightly changed. Just try:

`df = df.astype("string")`

Comment: Can you add the link to the documentation where you read about that please?

Comment: @CarloZanocco, here is a reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-types

Comment: Here you go: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes

Comment: Thank you! Just another question, why printing `df.info()` show `first    380 non-null object` and not `first    380 non-null string`?

Comment: I do not want to make all columns a string, just first and second. Where need I to put columns name, which I want to convert?

Comment: @John_caShyyy df['first'] = df['first'].astype("string")